# Rails - How do you stop custom validators from running on optional fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord, customvalidator

I have a model called `Client` which runs a custom phone number validator to see if a given phone number is valid (`validates :phone_number, :run_custom_validator => true`). The problem is that this phone number field should not be required, its optional, but the validator runs every time even when no phone number is given. How do I get the validator to run only when a phone number is given? Any responses would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the custom phone number validator, on the first line put the following:

```
return if phone_number.blank?
```